# navigation link to travel through respected category

Tags: wordpress

How to make navigation link to travel through respected category in **single.php** file in Wordpress

```
<nav id="nav-single">
   <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e('Post navigation', 'twentyeleven'); ?></h3>
   <?php previous_post_link('%link', __('<div class="nav-previous"></div>', 'twentyeleven')); ?>
   <?php next_post_link('%link', __('<div class="nav-next"></div>', 'twentyeleven')); ?>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i got it...making the third parameter toTRUE ($in_samecat = TRUE) will traverse it through the same category...and thanks

`<nav id="nav-single">
   <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e('Post navigation', 'twentyeleven'); ?></h3>
   <?php previous_post_link('%link', __('<div class="nav-previous"></div>', 'twentyeleven'),TRUE); ?>
   <?php next_post_link('%link', __('<div class="nav-next"></div>', 'twentyeleven'),TRUE); ?>
</nav>`